# Intellij disable new line before annotated field for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, autoformatting

IntelliJ autoformat keeps adding a blank lines between class field declarations having annotations.
Do you know how to disable it?
This happens for kotlin files since does not work like that for java files.

Example, between each `var` intellij adds a blank line each time I execute autoformat.

```
class Resign : UnitTest() {
    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var resignService: ResignServiceImpl

    @Mock
    private lateinit var actionAccess: ActionAccess

    @Mock
    private lateinit var userReportConverter: UserReportConverter

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was fixed in [KT-37891](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37891). The option to disable this behavior should be available in the next plugin version.

You may also consider voting for [KT-32185](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32185): 'More code style options for minimum blank lines'

Answer (score 0):

- Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Editor</kbd> > <kbd>Code style</kbd> > <kbd>Kotlin</kbd> > <kbd>Wrapping and Braces</kbd>.
- Change **Property annotations** to "Do not wrap" or "Wrap if long".

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However that is not the configuration. That configuration is to add a line between annotation and the field it annotates. But once modified intellij still add a blank line between the annotation and the previous field declared.

Comment: Ok I see. There's doesn't seem to be anything for that then. Maybe open an issue on their issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

No answer properly points out the exact name of the configuration. Under the Kotlin code style, it can be found on the *"Blank Lines"* tab, with the name *"Before declaration with comment or annotation"*.

For me, this defaulted to 1. Setting it to 0 let's me decide myself whether I want a new line or not.

[image: No new line]